# SpringBoot - Separating RestControllers from MVCControllers

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to create an Application with 2 separeted paths, one for API, other for MVC.

I created 2 ServletRegistrationBean. The first one for `/*` and the second one for `/api/v1/*`

The both contexts is working well, the problem is both answer all controllers.

I'm testing 2 paths:

- `/home` for MVC Controller
- `/health` for Rest Controller

But all paths below work.

- `/api/v1/home`
- `/api/v1/health`
- `/home`
- `/health`

I just want to the paths below works

- `/home`
- `/api/v1/health`

  ```
  @Configuration
  @EnableWebMvc
  public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

          @Bean
          public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherAPIServletRegistration() {
              AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
              context.scan(HealthController.class.getPackage().getName());

              DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet();
              servlet.setApplicationContext(context);

              ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/api/v1/*");

              registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
              registration.setName("api-v1");

              return registration;
          }

          @Bean
          public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {
              AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
              context.scan(HomeController.class.getPackage().getName());

              DispatcherServlet servlet = new DispatcherServlet();
              servlet.setApplicationContext(context);

              ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/*");

              registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
              registration.setName("web-mvc");

              return registration;
          }

  }
  ```

Comment: What package are your controllers under?

Comment: HomeController - `br.com.myapp.controller.web`
HealthController - `br.com.myapp.controller.rest`